# erlang-mysql-driver,error info:already_started,

Tags: mysql, erlang

when i use erlang-mysql-driver to connect mysql, the error info is already_started,what should i do?
   eg:

```
ConnRet = mysql:start_link(p1, 
                               MysqlConfig#config.ip,
                               MysqlConfig#config.port,
                               MysqlConfig#config.user,
                               MysqlConfig#config.passwd,
                               MysqlConfig#config.database),
    case ConnRet of
        {ok, _} ->
        {error, ConnErr} ->
            lager:debug("conn mysql error : ~p ~n", [ConnErr]),
```

ConnErr is {already_started,<0.2690.0>}
   thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite descriptive :) It means, that connection is already started. You can prepare for that situation using:

```
case ConnRet of
    {ok, _} -> do_something(...);
    {error, {already_started, _}} -> do_something(...);
    {error, ConnErr} ->
        lager:error("conn mysql error : ~p ~n", [ConnErr])
end,
```

If you are not sure, if the connection details of previous connection are valid, simply stop the `mysql` application and try to start it again.